# Restrict CA to issue certficates for one domain or to be able to sign just one server certificate

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, openssl

I have a server and I want my iPhone to connect to it securely. However, I cannot just install the self-signed server certificate on my iPhone. When I install the profile (that's what they call the certificate), it says "Not verified".

Normally, you would go to CA Trust settings and enable full trust for the certificate. BUT I deliberately made the certificate with `critical,CA:false` constraint. That's the reason it does not show in the CA Trust settings.

Why did I do it -- I just need to install the single certificate and I don't want to totally compromise my iPhone security, if my CA credentials got stolen.

Do this have a solution? iOS probably requires a CA to trust a certificate, but I don't want a possibility to create certificates at all (beside the one), or at least for another domains.

---

One potential "solution" might be to create the CA, sign the server certificate and then delete the CA key, as it would not be needed and would live for a shorter time (lower chance to get stolen).

However, people except me wouldn't be stoked to install it. (I don't want to buy a certificate as its a home project and I don't even have a domain name, just the IP address.)

The certificate complies with apple's current requirements for server certificates. (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176)

Comment: Why not go with a Lets encrypt certificate? They're free...

Comment: @vidarlo you have to a domain name

Comment: @Adam is this just for your own personal use, or are you creating something that you want others to establish a trusted connection to?

Comment: @Sam3000 More or less personal, or people I know

Comment: @Adam you can get some domains for under a dollar a year, if price is an issue.

Comment: @multithr3at3d maybe the first year (could do it every year though), then it easily ramps up tenfold. I don’t want to support the business. I could host my own dns server ( cannot add entry to /etc/hosts on normal iOS), but looks that needs to be set for each WiFi connection and won’t work on cellular (unless some VPN hack I’ve seen on SE).

Comment: As I need it for Siri Shortcuts app, I could also use the SSH function instead of certificates. But for the verification of the authenticity of the server it displays a 128 bit hash = md5? which is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you need to use a CA and make it trusted. If you control and secure the CA key pair, you can be more confident that others won't sign certs with your CA.

Your idea of creating the CA then deleting (I would suggest shredding instead) would fit your purpose. If others need to trust the CA you created for the product to work on their devices, you can distribute the fingerprint in person for them to validate it.